# PowerShell DSC: The data source could not process the filter

Tags: powershell, dsc

Afternoon!

I have run into an issue with PowerShell DSC (the Start-DscConfiguration cmdlet specifically) 2 days trying to figure it out, now I am here :)

I am getting the following error for a specific MOF file, prior MOFs run fine.

```
The data source could not process the filter. The filter might be missing or it might be invalid. Change the filter
and try the request again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8033801a
```

EDIT: Has anyone experienced this error before? I can share the MOF file in question, with some restricted info removed. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue here wasn't with PowerShell DSC, rather just PowerShell in itself.

I had a cmdlet within a switch block. As an example:

```
Switch($item){
  {$_ -eq $true}{do something}
  {$_ -eq $fales}{do something}

  get-service -name $item
}
```

It was the *get-service* cmdlet that could not be filtered.